# How to get the device token in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, devicetoken

I'm trying to get the device token, for this i'm using `FirebaseMessaging`. here is my code to get the token.

```
@override
  void initState()  {
 FirebaseMessaging? _firebaseMessaging;
 _firebaseMessaging?.getToken().then((token){
      print("token is $token");
});
}
```

but it print nothing. Please help how to do this.

Comment: Another place to look is your messaging provider upstream of Firebase. For example, using Iterable.com to manage our Push Notification campaigns, when the device Allow Notifications, the Iterable user profile gains a `devices.token` field with the same value. https://support.iterable.com/hc/en-us/articles/217744303-User-Profile-Fields-Used-by-Iterable#devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create the FirebaseMessaging instance. Change to:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance; // Change here
  _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
    print("token is $token");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save token into firestore

```
final FirebaseMessaging _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
late String currentToken;
String userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
@override
void initState() {
_messaging.getToken().then((value) {
  print(value);
  if (mounted)
    setState(() {
      currentToken = value!;
    });
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('pushtokens')
      .doc(userId)
      .set({'token': value!, 'createdAt': DateTime.now()});
 });
```